# Cat licking me after eating mouse

Tags: fiqh, fatwa

Assalamualikum my cat was eating a mouse and immediately after eating it he licked my hand is my hand najis. Is blood of a mouse najis

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A Site about Islam.To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking out [help].The hand of a living human is not najis by default, but it can come in touch with najasa.

Comment: @Medi1Saif iam asking is blood of a mouse najis?